# Как запустить браузер внутри своей программы Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, webbrowser

Например, Visual studio при попытке сообщить о проблеме выводится такое окно: [image: screen]
В котором красным прямоугольником выделено вкрапление браузера. При помощи чего это можно сделать в своем приложении на Qt, чтобы внутри какого то виджета отображалось окно браузера по умолчанию? И как можно отдавать команду обновления страницы этому вкраплению браузера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз *yrHeTaTeJlb* не хочет добавить современный код в свой ответ, держите:

```
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QWebEngineView view;
    view.load(QUrl("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553640/Как-запустить-браузер-внутри-своей-программы-qt"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

и в проектном файле:

```
QT += gui webenginewidgets
```

Comment: Теперь ошибки в проектном файле пропали, но не удается скомпилировать из-за ошибки С1083 - невозможно найти/открыть включаемый файл QWebEngineView... Очень странно, даже сам Qt Creator подсказывает эту библиотеку, а скопмпилировать не дает.

Comment: @Nik, `qmake` на проекте сделайте.

Comment: А смотрите, я все правильно делаю с qmake: Я добавил путь к qmake.exe в переменную Path и теперь в командной строке из каталога с проектом выполняю qmake projectname.pro верно?

Comment: @Nik, Вы не QtCreator используете?

Comment: Да, его использую.

Comment: @Nik, правой кнопкой по проекту -> Run qmake

Comment: а команду make как в qt creator выполнить?

Comment: @Nik, в настройках проекта можно всё что угодно настроить, только зачем? В целом, это уже отдельные вопросы всё. Комментарии не предназначены для расширенных дискуссий.

Answer (score 5):

Ну если на уровне hello world, то вот вам пример из книги Макса Шлее, посвященной Qt 5.3

```
#include<QtWidgets>
#include<QtWebKitWidgets>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebView webView;
    webView.load(QUrl("http://www.bhv.ru"));
    webView.show()
    return app.exec();
}
```

В *.pro файле должно быть `QT += widgets webkit webkitwidgets`
Подробно эта тема разобрана в 46 главе книги

> Qt 5.3. Профессиональное программирование на C++

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но при попытке включить строку QT += widgets webkit webkitwidgets в pro файл я получаю ошибку: "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit webkitwidgets". А полученный браузер будет обладать теми же способностями для отображения, что и, например хром? т. е. html5, css3 и другие новые вещи?

Comment: Перепишите пример с новыми технологиями, webkit уже, вероятно, выпилили. Там теперь основанный на Chromium движок.

Comment: @ixSci на самом деле мне бы просто открывать уже установленный в системе браузер по умолчанию, а не писать свой... Это можно как-то сделать?

Comment: @Nik, а какая версия библиотеки?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb qt 5.7. Но говорю же, мне бы не хотелось писать свой браузер, можно ли запускать уже установленный в системе по умолчанию?

Comment: @Nik, браузер это программа, программу внутри программы запускать нельзя. В студийном примере так же используются компоненты IE внутри студии, посредством(скорее всего) WPFного WebView, никакой IE внутри студии не запускается. Если Вам нужно открыть URL в браузере, а не внутри программы, тогда это делается ещё проще, но по другому.

Comment: @Nik, ну да в в 5.7 уже нет webkit. Можете посмотреть вот эту [ссылку](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html). Должно помочь

Comment: @ixSci в принципе, меня устроит и вариант открытия URL в браузере, но не простого открытия, а с возможностью обновления страницы из моего qt приложения. По сути, я хочу реализовать нечто наподобие LivePreview в Brackets. В Brackets при активации опции живого превью открывается страница с адресом localhost:3727/filename и обновляется по мере изменения кода. Для этого нужно создавать свой сервер?

Comment: @Nik, я не знаю как это работает, поэтому ничего сказать по этому поводу не могу.